# How specify an example of type List<String> in Swagger @ApiModelProperty annotation?

Tags: java, spring, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

When I specify an `@ApiModelProperty`, and it's of type `List<String>`, the example does not show properly.

All of the following show incorrectly:

```
@ApiModelProperty(
    value = "Decr",

    dataType = "List",
    //dataType = "java.util.List",
    //dataType = "java.util.List<String>",
    //dataType = "List<String>",
    //dataType = "java.util.ArrayList",
    //dataType = "array",

    example = "Somevalue",
    //example = "[Somevalue]",
    //example = "[\"Somevalue\"]"
)
```

What is the proper way to do this?

(Using Swagger/Swagger-UI 2.5.0)

Comment: Have you found a solution? I am struggling with the same problem in Springfox 3.0.0, no solution. See https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/3863